# Qt GUI platform for mobile robot

Tags: ros, robot, mobile, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am now currently developing a mobile robot and I wish to create a GUI by using Qt to control my mobile robot. I would like to ask is there any sample/example of Qt based GUI that is already working to control a mobile robot that is suitable for me to refer to.

All I can find right now is just this source https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone/tree/hydro-devel/src/UINode and the overall concept is a bit overwhelming and beyond my comprehension as I only have a short experience with both Qt and C++ .

Could anybody tell me the basic step from how to create and to use the GUI to control a mobile robot. I would very much appreciate if there is any other source that I could understand and modify.

Thanks very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200209/qt-gui-platform-for-mobile-robot/) by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS has Qt-based GUI framework and toolset called [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt). I recommend to browse through first the list of [some existing tools](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Plugins) and see if there's anything that might fit your needs, before starting your own GUI tools from scratch. For mobile robots in particular, I can think of [rqt_robot_steering](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_robot_steering) for operating wheels at minimum.

`rqt` provides set of [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt#Instructions) to build your own GUI based on rqt framework.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2014-12-31**:
thanks for the reply. I am still little bit somehow confuse about the rqt plugin/tools. How can I use the them? Do I just need to start up my robot and able to use the rqt_robot_steering to control my mobile robot? Is there any step required in between?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-12-31**:
Exactly; just fire up robot's ROS processes and open rqt tools. Note that `rqt_robot_steering` by default interacts with a specific name topic so you might have to edit it by yourself (as I [recently added to its wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/rqt_robot_steering?action=diff&rev2=3&rev1=1)).

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-01-15**:
thank you. I only managed to try it recently. It works and I am able to move my robot. However, one problem is that my robot does not move accordingly to the steering. eg: I wanted to move forward but my robot is moving diagonally.
Sorry for replying here as I am not sure on starting a new thread.